# Android app goes back to the previous activity instead of the next activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-activity

Currently my app has 4 activities and everything is fine as I want it to be until the app comes to the 3rd activity. Instead of going to the next activity i.e, 4th activity. It goes back to the 2nd activity from the 3rd activity.

I also tried adding a button in the main activity which would take me directly to the 4th activity and when I clicked the button, the app just crashed.

In the third activity I have a count down timer and i want the app to go to the next activity after the timer is finished. So in the OnFinish function the code is:

```
override fun onFinish() {
                finish()
                val intent = Intent(this@ThirdActivity, FourthActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
        }
```

**Edit 1:**
In the logcat I was redirected to a line of code that caused the error. In the 4th activity, I declared a variable before the onCreate method and when I removed that line, the 4th activity was running fine but I actually want that variable declared.

```
private val vibrator = getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
```

and I declared it before the OnCreate method because i was able to call the `vibrator.cancel()` in the setOnClickListener of a button and if I declare the variable-- Vibrator in the function I created to vibrate the device then i get an unresolved reference error where i call the `vibrator.cancel()` inside the setOnClickListener

The code where I get unresolved reference error after declaring the variable "vibrator" in the vibrate function:

```
btnFinish.setOnClickListener{
        finish()
        vibrator.cancel()
    }
```

**Edit 2:**

I somehow made the app run and everything is running fine.

The vibrate function:

```
private fun vibrate(context: Context){
    val vibrator = getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        vibrator.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createWaveform(pattern,-1))
    }
    else{
        vibrator.vibrate(500)
    }
}
```

And i called it in the onCreate:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_finish)

    vibrate(this@FinishActivity)
```

I also had to declare the variable again in the onDestroy Method XD and then stopped  the vibration

```
override fun onDestroy() {
    val vibrator = getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
    super.onDestroy()
    vibrator.cancel()
}
```

Comment: _"when I clicked the button, the app just crashed"_. Then you should add the stacktrace from the crash to your question, and point out any places in your code that the stacktrace refers to.

Comment: Your question is still missing some important information, like where exactly you put that call to `setOnClickListener`. I don't see why you can't put both `val vibrator = getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator` and the `setOnClickLister` call inside `onCreate`.

Comment: I did try that. The vibrator variable is also used in a function in that activity and if i declare that variable in the onCreate then the vibrator variable used in the function of that activity gives an unresolved reference error.

Comment: So have multiple local `vibrator` variables. Or make `vibrator` a nullable or `lateinit` member variable that you initialize in `onCreate`.

Comment: I declared the variable twice. Once in the onCreate and another in the function and it's working fine. Thank you

Comment: Can you please add the code of your `ThirdActivity` where you declare, initialize and use your `vibrator` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private val vibrator = getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
```

This is failing because it's really a call to `context.getSystemService`, and your `Activity` doesn't have a `context` when it's first constructed, so initialising the variable this way is going to fail (the error you got probably told you this).

There's three main approaches you could take - the first two involve you initialising `vibrator` when you **do** have what you need (a `context` in this case), e.g. in `onCreate`

```
private var vibrator1: Vibrator? = null
private lateinit var vibrator2: Vibrator
private val vibrator3: Vibrator by lazy {
    getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
}

fun onCreate() {
    vibrator1 =  getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
    vibrator2 =  getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
    // vibrator3 will assign itself when you first access it
}
```

So for the first two, you need to set them.

The first one, initialising it to null just because it needs to be set to *something* when you declare it, is simple - but now `vibrator` is nullable, you need to null-check it everywhere, and it's not *actually* ever supposed to be null, you're using nullability as a workaround, and it's overcomplicating things.

The second, `lateinit`, is a promise that you'll set a value on it before anything tries to read it. So you don't need to give it an initial value, you just need to be careful that you assign it early enough. It does have to be a `var` instead of a `val` now though

The third one, using `lazy`, basically initialises the value the first time something accesses it. It's a bit like a `lateinit` that assigns itself by running the code in the lambda. And it's a `val`! All you need to worry about here is that the first access happens when the lambda can successfully run - in this case, you need that `context`. But nothing's accessing `vibrator` before the activity has its context, so it's all good

There are pros and cons for these, but it's good to be aware of them. Especially `lateinit`, it's Kotlin's way of having its nullability/null-checking system work cleanly for things that can't be initialised immediately, which happens a lot in Android with its lifecycle callbacks

Comment: Oh wow. Thank you for your detailed answer. I learned a lot. I tested your code and everything worked fine except that it asked me to change val vibrator1 to var. Can you please check my question again? I updated it. I actually found a fix too where i declared the vibrator variable just twice. I know it may bring up some issues in the future but yeah that worked too.

Comment: Oh sorry that was a mistake, `vibrator1` definitely needs to be a `var` (re-assigning it is the whole point!). And you're not really declaring the same variable twice, you're just getting two separate references to the system's `Vibrator` service. Either way is fine, it's more efficient to just do it once (with a member variable, instead of getting it every time you call the function) but whether it matters depends on how often you call that function. You just need to be sure the activity has that implicit `context` when you call `getSystemService` - by the time `onCreate` happens, it's got it

Answer (score 0):

You are calling finish() method, this calls the onDestroy() life cycle method, check that part it's possible that there's code there that's causing your problem. Or else if possible, please try to remove the call to the finish() and see what's going to happen.